# Spatial Query plugin broken in MacOS version?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm running QGIS 1.7.4-4 on a MacOS 1.6.8.
I'm trying to use the "Spatial Query" plugin but it's not loading.
The plugin is activated and I can see it in the main menu Plugins > Spatial Query > Spatial Query but when I click on it no window appears, nothing happens.
I've tried to deactivate it, restart QGIS, reactivate, but nothing changes.

Any help?

Comment: I'm finding the same thing with several plugins. OSX 10.7.3 and QGIS 1.7.4 and QGIS 1.9. Nothing happens, not even an error, and there's nothing in the logs that points to a problem.

Comment: Please open bug reports to inform the developers. I've just tested the Windows version and it works fine.

Comment: It's now [reported](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5543)!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like another plugin that connects the launching action's activated() signal to its installed gui elements.

https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/src/plugins/spatialquery/qgsspatialqueryplugin.cpp#L82

That signal is [no longer supported under Qt 4.8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#signals), which is what QGIS 1.7.4 is built against/bundled with on Mac OS X. I have seen this problem with other plugins (now both C++ and Python).

I have not tested this, but changing the signal to 'triggered()' in the noted file might fix the problem. You can test it with re-compiling the latest master branch (1.8 RC 1, not 1.9 right now, as it is readying for release).

(*I have added this to Simbamangu's bug report. Can someone compile and test fix? I won't be able to for a couple of days.*)